# Maximum current rating of MT60 for AMASS MT60 connectors

Tags: connector, power-connector

I have seen AMASS MT60 connectors listed as 30 A continuous and 45 A, and even sometimes 60 A.

I would like to use them to connect REV SparkMax outputs (3 lines) to Neo motors.

The unofficial 'standard' for FRC for 12 AWG lines for years have been Anderson PP45.  But some have been moving to WAGO 221 inline.  [REV](https://www.revrobotics.com/rev-15-2491/) has a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4QVwAT4vd4g) of the usage of these connectors under 80 A draw.

The current rating for the PP45 is supposed to be 45 A, where as I sometimes see the WAGOs listed as 20 A, 32 A or the same line that out performed the PP45.
Given the oddness with the different ratings, and the meltdown of the 45 in the above video.  How do you feel about the MT60 bullet.
NEO motors have a an empirical stall current of 105 A and are frequently software limited to 80 A in FRC applications (though not mandatory) would we be safe with MT60?

Answer (score 1):

Don't believe the vendors: they are incentivized to exaggerate for the sake of sales.

Instead, look at the official spec sheet.

http://www.china-amass.com/mobile.php/product/contain/1B504529k88Rp8g1

It says:

Rated current: 35 A.

> NEO motors have a an empirical stall current of 105 A and are frequently software limited to 80 A in FRC applications (though not mandatory) would we be safe with MT60?

No. Unless you can configure the motor controller (you *do* have a motor controller, right?) for 35 A max.

Comment: And yet the datasheet for MT60 says 30A (metal) and 60A (plastic), whatever that means. Ratings are specified under different conditions, and different electrical codes. Same connector can be rated differently in different jurisdictions.

Comment: Kindly link to that datasheet so I may see for myself.

Comment: Here you go : https://www.shoptronica.com/ficheros/MT60.pdf

Comment: @JustMe. Thank you. The left two columns have one set of data, the right two columns have a different set. Metal and Plastic are unrelated to the current rating. RC = 30 A is the continuous current rating. MC = 60 A is the peak current rating.